# How to add dynamic Data to IBM carbon table in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, carbon-design-system

I am using [carbon-component-angular](https://github.com/IBM/carbon-components-angular#readme) and trying to create Data table using dynamic data coming from an api which looks something like this.

```
const data = [
{
    id: 0,
    firstName: "Name 1",
    lastname: "Lastname 1",
    contactNo: "287785452",
    gender: "male",
    age: "30",
    dateOfBirth: "12/08/1990",
    address: "Austrailia"
  },    
  {
    id: 1,
    firstName: "Name 2",
    lastname: "Lastname 2",
    contactNo: "287785452",
    gender: "male",
    age: "30",
    dateOfBirth: "12/08/1990",
    address: "France"
  }
]
```

My Html

```
<ibm-table-container>
  <ibm-table-header>
    <h4 ibmTableHeaderTitle>All user's profiles</h4>
    <p>List of all user's Profile</p>
  </ibm-table-header>
  <ibm-table-toolbar [model]="model">
    <ibm-table-toolbar-content>
      <ibm-table-toolbar-search
        (change)="searchValueChange($event.value)"
        [expandable]=" true "
      >
      </ibm-table-toolbar-search>
    </ibm-table-toolbar-content>
  </ibm-table-toolbar>

  <ibm-table [model]="model">No Data </ibm-table>
  <ibm-pagination
    [model]="model "
    [itemsPerPageOptions]="itemsPerPageOptions "
    (selectPage)="selectPage($event) "
  >
  </ibm-pagination>
</ibm-table-container>
```

The header and Data that I define in component.ts file

```
import {
  TableModel,
  TableHeaderItem,
  TableItem,
  PaginationModel,
} from "carbon-components-angular";

export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {
model = new TableModel()

ngOnInit(){

     this.model.header = [
      new FilterableHeaderItem({
        data: "Unique Id",
        filterTemplate: this.filter,
        filterFooter: this.filterFooter,
      }),
      new TableHeaderItem({ data: "Name" }),
      new TableHeaderItem({ data: "Place" }),
    ]; 
    
    let newData = [];

    //this.data from above data array
    for (let profile of this.data) {
      newData.push(
        new TableItem({ data: profile.id }),
        new TableItem({ data: profile.firstName }),
        new TableItem({ data: profile.address }),
      );
    }
    this.model.data = newdata;
 }
}
```

I have tried the code above but the table is not showing only the part in `<ibm-table-header>` is showing. Can somebody help me with this?

[Carbon Component for angular documentation(Table)](https://angular.carbondesignsystem.com/?path=/story/components-table--with-pagination)

Answer (score 0):

```
async ngOnInit(){

     this.model.header = [
      new FilterableHeaderItem({
        data: "Unique Id",
        filterTemplate: this.filter,
        filterFooter: this.filterFooter,
      }),
      new TableHeaderItem({ data: "Name" }),
      new TableHeaderItem({ data: "Place" }),
    ]; 
    
    let newData = [];

    //this.data from above data array
    await for (let profile of this.data) {
      newData.push(
        new TableItem({ data: profile.id }),
        new TableItem({ data: profile.firstName }),
        new TableItem({ data: profile.address }),
      );
    }
    this.model.data = newdata;
 }
}
```

Comment: There is no proper documentation for angular Carbon. Only theories they provided in userstory and documents. Not explained with examples. It's very hard to understand angular Carbon. Hope they will provide enough material at one place.